# Como retornar apenas a data do último commit?

Tags: git, commit

Eu sei que se eu utilizar o comando `git log` consigo ver os ids dos commits realizados no meu repositório e, se usar `git rev-parse HEAD`, consigo ver o nome do último commit. Porém eu precisava de retornar apenas a informação da data do meu último commit.

Exemplo:

```bsh
commit 49fb9be4b5e655dd8104e79eb5dc824cc7c782d1 
Author: WallaceMaxters 
Date:   Tue Nov 17 14:44:03 2020 -0300

    alteração 3

commit 8a94c729e8095060afb3d58402b113852b9429ff 
Author: WallaceMaxters 
Date:   Tue Nov 10 16:31:45 2020 -0300

    alteração 2

commit e1b958709236f81d7e11d5bb38ab46b4a16b9b62
Author: WallaceMaxters 
Date:   Tue Oct 27 16:11:30 2020 -0300

    alteração 1
```

No caso acima, gostaria de retornar **apenas a data** `Tue Nov 17 14:44:03 2020 -0300` através de algum dos comandos do `git`.

É possível fazer isso? Preciso apenas da informação da data referente ao último commit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a opção `--format`, utilizando o *placeholder* `%cd`, assim:

```
git log --format=%cd
```

Que retorna somente as *datas* para os últimos *commits*. Para retornar a data do último *commit*, basta utilizar o range `-1`. Assim:

```
git log --format=%cd -1
```

A opção `--format` (do comando `git log`) funciona com base no que a documentação do Git se refere como *pretty-formats*. Veja a [referência](https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats) para os outros casos de formatação.

Nesse caso, o *placeholder* `%cd`, de acordo com a documentação:

> `%cd`
> committer date (format respects --date= option)

Note que, conforme a própria documentação do *placeholder* `%cd` aponta, a opção `--date` é respeitada. Desse modo, você pode alterar o "padrão" da data. Veja:

```
$ git log  --format=%cd -1
Mon Oct 26 12:14:45 2020 -0300

$ git log --date=iso --format=%cd -1
2020-10-26 12:14:45 -0300
```

<sup>Consulte a documentação de [`--date`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---dateltformatgt) para saber mais.</sup>